# Delayed delete of shift-deleted files

Tags: operating-systems

Sometimes when we do a shift-delete we realise only after a certain while that we have deleted the wrong file! (has happened with me). I just have an idea to avert this disaster! If the OS could delete the file in question only after a certain period of time, the chances of recovery are high in that certain period, even in case of any number of disc writes after deletion.If that period of time is user configurable, that would be great!Can OS experts around here throw light on the feasibility of its implementation?

Comment: You mean you want to implement something like a normal `delete`. Where the files are 'saved' for a period (until the bin is emptied)?

Comment: I suppose that when you talk about The Operating System you actually mean your own computer's operating system. Don't forget to mention which one it is.

Answer (score 5):

This is already implemented. Do not hold the shift key when pressing delete and the file goes into your recycle bin where you can recover it any time you like.  At the time you decide, empty the recycle bin and they are then deleted (sort of).